# Something went wrong

Tags: configuration, network-configuration

I've searched through the tips/faq and I cannot find an answer. I also have went through pages of google trying to get help on my own.  I have deleted it and reinstalled it a few times, and each time I get Something Went wrong. Tor is not working in this browser. It's on imac. I'm not sure how to fix it, and I cannot seem to find the answers on my own. Please help. Log is below.

2/4/17, 21:29:26.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop

2/4/17, 21:29:26.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit

2/4/17, 21:29:27.700 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.

2/4/17, 21:29:27.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done

2/4/17, 21:29:28.600 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.

2/4/17, 21:29:28.800 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.